# K-Means clustering in QGIS (Attribute based clustering)

Tags: qgis, clustering, qgis-2.18, vrt

In the 2.18.4 and 2.18.5 version of QGIS K-means clustering was moved to a plugin called **'Attribute based clustering'**. However, I am working with a virtual raster dataset (vrt.) and the current version of he plugin works with vectors.

Is there another method i can use to  perform an **unsupervised K-means clustering** in QGIS?

Comment: do you mean k-means classification for rasters? There's one in Orfeo Toolbox - not tried this with a VRT though. You'll need to install Orfeo toolbox yourself, but once done you can access it through Processing.

Comment: Hi, Steve Kay. I did install the Orfeo toolbox but was unable to find the unsupervised k-means classification through the processing tab. Actually, I wasn't able to find any unsupervised methods of classification. I though the 'Attribute based clustering' might work but its only works with vectors and I have raster data.

Comment: In my setting (OTB 5.10.0) it is listed under `Learning` tree. (As already commented by @StevenKay , it may not work well with VRT.)

Comment: Looked through SAGA itself and the unsupervised clustering is there (in SAGA). However I cant find it in QGIS itself. Do any of you know a way to associate the unsupervised KMeans clustering into QGIS. p.s.: i  will remove my question once i locate the Kmeans clustering, to not confuse others.

Comment: Nowadays it is in SAGA>Image analysis>K-means clustering for grids.

Comment: Hello! Yes nowadays it is in SAGA, but it is called "K-means clustering for Rasters" and there is a problem in my case because there is an specific problem: "SAGA version 7.8.2 is not officially supported - algorithms may encounter issues"